# Amazon Mechanical Turk API. Example Creating a HIT from PHP

Tags: php, api, mechanicalturk

I need to create a HIT using the Amazon Mechanical Turk API from PHP. There's no examples at the official documentation and no PHP librearies or SDK. Does anyone know how to do this? any kind of help is appreciated, a PHP example will be great.

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question by now, but in case others find it via Google search (as I did), here is another PHP library for Turk. I haven't tried it yet, and YMMV:

https://github.com/jackbot/PHP-Mechanical-Turk

Answer (score 2):

Stanford's CS50 course produces [Turk50](https://manual.cs50.net/Turk50), it "supports the entirety of Mechanical Turk's API" and is essentially a wrapper for AMT's SOAP interface,

> Turk50 is a PHP library that makes it "easier for you to build solutions leveraging Amazon Mechanical Turk". Although an SDK exists for PHP ... odds are you'll find Turk50's learning curve lower.

Answer (score 0):

A complete API for AMT appears here:

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7196-PHP-Setup-crowdsourcing-tasks-with-Mechanical-Turk-API.html

Comment: Can you please post on github or a site that doesn't require a login to download?